# Merging two documents with different footers docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

Scenario:

- Document 1 has footer 1
- Document 2 has footer 2

Expected outcome should be:

Document 3 made merging document 1 and 2 with footers preserved for document 1 and document 2.

How can we achieve this using docx4j ?

I have tried merging two documents using below code:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage f = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(first);
WordprocessingMLPackage s= WordprocessingMLPackage.load(second);
    List body1 = s.getMainDocumentPart().getJAXBNodesViaXPath("//w:body", false);
            for (Object b : body1) {
                List filhos = ((org.docx4j.wml.Body) b).getContent();
                for (Object k : filhos)
                    {f.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(k);
                    }
            }
```

But the resultant merge applies footer of first document to the entire document, thus the second document footer gets lost.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the relevant footer to the document (addTargetPart), then reference it from inside a sectPr element.  Footer references reference a footer part by their rel id.

Alternatively, you could use our commercial Docx4j Enterprise, which includes MergeDocx for handling all the issues which arise when you try to join 2 Word documents together.

Comment: But won't addTargetPart add a single footer to the entire document? I want 2 different footers when merging 2 different documents . The resultant document should contain 2 footers of both the documents when merged.

Comment: You need to understand that headers/footers are specified in sectPr elements (and that a sectPr element can specify a single header/footer, or something more complex eg odd/even), and that a document can contain more than one section (ie multiple sectPr elements).  When you addTargetPart, you get back a relId which you using within the header/footer ref in a sectPr.